# How do I treat injuries in a caravan?

Tags: rimworld

One of my caravans was attacked by some manhunting Wargs and someone sustained some minor injuries. How do I treat this person while he is still in the caravan?

Comment: There is also a mod that allows caravans to set up camp. You basically load a small map (not the usual size) and can quickly set up a camp to do some basic stuff before packing up and leaving again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make temporary beds and treat the wounds like you normally would if you were at the colony with a bed (aka having another person treat the wounds when they are in a medical bed).

(around 9:00 we can see this in the Alpha 16 preview)

Answer (score 2):

Two very accessible, but not immediately obvious ways:

- Under **Architect** > **Furniture**, place a **Sleeping Spot**
- If you added **Bedrolls** to your caravan, grab one and place it on the ground

Since a bed is required in order to treat injuries, either option will allow another colonist to tend to injuries.